# Internal reference within a graph using graphviz in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, graphviz, cross-reference

I am trying to create a graph using graphviz in my Sphinx documentation.
I managed to include a `href` in the graph to link an external web page (good example here https://jhermann.github.io/blog/python/documentation/2020/03/25/sphinx_ext_graphviz.html).
I would now like do the same but referencing another page of my documentation (using something like `` :ref:`another page of my documentation` ``  instead of the `href`). Expected result is: you click on a node of the graph and it opens the corresponding documentation page/ section.
Is this possible? Any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that any value that you put in an `href` attribute that works in HTML would also work in graphviz. Try adding a relative path for its value, for example:

```
.. graphviz::
    :name: name

     digraph "my-digraph" {
         my [label="my-label",
             shape="component",
             href="relative/path/to/file.html"
             target="_blank"];
     }
```

Comment: This is only a workaround. You have to know the location of the file you're referencing. A better solution would allow to use `:ref:\`...\`` as the OP suggested - this way I could move the target file around without having to update the hrefs.

Comment: @michcio1234 did you actually try your own suggestion? What was the result?

Comment: it was not a suggestion of working solution, sorry for a misunderstanding. I know it doesn't work. I just tried to explain what I was looking for but didn't find in your solution.